# How to setup AWS rds with SSL with phpmyadmin

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I want to encrypt the connection to db from phpmyadmin using SSL. I am confused on how to use bundle certificate

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to download the certificate by visiting here:
[Download an SSL certificate for your managed database in Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-download-ssl-certificate-for-managed-database)

Here is a direct link for combined ca bundle:
[rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem)

Now copy this 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem' file to your phpMyAdmin folder and search for config.inc.php file.

open this file (config.inc.php) in notepad or in any text editor and write the below lines:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_mode'] = 'VERIFY_IDENTITY';
```

Now save the file and visit you host (http://localhost/phpMyAdmin).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it up as described in the docs using [$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl']](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl) option:

> Whether to **enable SSL** for the connection between phpMyAdmin and the MySQL server to secure the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Upload the rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem to some path that phpMyAdmin can access.

Then set the following configuration vars in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca_path'] = '/path/to/';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_key'] = 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_cert'] = 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '/path/to/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem';
```

Comment: i am only using ssl_ca and it still works. what about key and cert . I ignored it as there is nothing given for it